# Style jQueryUI element created in Angular2 Component

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-ui, angular

I am trying to include a jQueryUI range slider inside of an Angular2 Component.

doubleRange.ts:

```
/// <reference path="../../../../../typings/jquery/jquery.d.ts" />
/// <reference path="../../../../../typings/jqueryui/jqueryui.d.ts" />
import { Component, ElementRef, AfterViewInit, Renderer } from 'angular2/angular2'

declare var jQuery:JQueryStatic;

@Component({
    selector: 'double-range',
    template: `<div id="slider"></div>`, 
    styleUrls: ['application/common/js/widgets/double-range-widget/double-range-widget.css'],
})
export class DoubleRangeWidget implements AfterViewInit{

    constructor(private m_elementRef: ElementRef, private m_renderer: Renderer) {
    }

    afterViewInit(){
        jQuery(this.m_elementRef.nativeElement).find("#slider").slider({
           range:true,
        });

    }
}
```

This works correctly and my generated dom looks like this :

```
<div id="slider" _ngcontent-xxx-3 class="ui-slider ui-slider-horizontal ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-corner-all">
    <div class="ui-slider-range ui-widget-header ui-corner-all" style="left: 36%; width: 34%;"></div>
    <span class="ui-slider-handle ui-state-default ui-corner-all" tabindex="0" style="left: 36%;"></span>
    <span class="ui-slider-handle ui-state-default ui-corner-all" tabindex="0" style="left: 70%;"></span>
<div>
```

The problem appears when i try to apply a new css to my component.
In my css file i write new properties for the ui-slider related classes but the css is applyed only to the `<div id="slider">` as it got the `_ngcontent-xxx-3` attribute but not to the within elements as they do not have that attribute.
Is there a way to tell Angular2 to had that attribute to all the element of a component even if generated by jQuery automatically ? I do not want to have to search into the DOM for that attribute and ad it manually to all the subelements in the afterViewInit.

PS: I am working with Angular2 version 2.0.0-alpha.46

Answer (score 3):

I think you need to switch view encapsulation to `None`

```
@Component({
    selector: 'double-range',
    template: `<div id="slider"></div>`, 
    styleUrls: ['application/common/js/widgets/double-range-widget/double-range-widget.css'],
    encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None,
})
```

Angular by default uses `ViewEncapsulation.Emulated`. View encapsulation is to prevent styles to bleed into other components.

See also

- http://blog.thoughtram.io/angular/2015/06/29/shadow-dom-strategies-in-angular2.html
- https://angular.io/docs/js/latest/api/core/ViewEncapsulation-enum.html

Comment: Thank you for your quick and correct answer. I have an other question : using ViewEncapsulation.None make that my css affect the whole html, is there a way to make it apply only to my component ?

Comment: I'm not sure, I'll need to investigate. I guess CSS will affect the element where it's added and children.